# SWAT 4 Context Menu in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to make an **interaction system** that use a small **context menu to choose what to do**. The same menu you command bots in SWAT4. you can use the **scroll wheel to select the option** and press the **Left mouse button to validate**.

If you have not played SWAT4 the menu look as follow:

[image: Swat4]

**What I have:**  When I aim at an object close enough, a little menu (panel with buttons) opens (`SetActive(true)`), but I made it with the editor. I don't see how to change the number of buttons and their positions on the fly, since every interactable object can have a number of options.

Here's the way I made the menu right now (I cant use the scroll wheel or mouse in it actually):

[image: The menu I have so far]

**Objects example:**
A **door** as these options: Open, LockPick, Blowing it
A **pile of cash** have only one option: Take...

**What I would like:**
A way to **create a custom menu while in game** with a **number of options** I can change, **options name**  that changes, **scroll up** to select above option, **scroll down** to select under and **left click** to validate.

**Conclusion:**
The way I tried with the basic menu setup is not a good way. I don't know if I can use `OnGui()` for this kind of stuff. And if `OnGui()` is the correct way to do this how can I accomplish the result I showed in the first picture.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could realize that menu ?

Comment: `OnGUI()` can be forced into working for this feature but it'd be a mess. You'll have a better time using [Unity's Layout Groups](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/grouping-and-layout-techniques-for-ui-components-2019-3).  They're made for this sort of complexity

Comment: Ok thanks, i will check that !(sorry for my english :/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's Done** :) (Thanks Foggzie)

If someone ever thinks of doing this type of menu at runtime here is how i did:

*First, i set up my menu:*

1)Create a **panel**.
2)Add a **vertical layout group** to it (or horizontal...).
3)Add a **content size fitter** to it, it's going to resize our panel automatically.

Then i added some buttons as child of the panel:

[image: And deactivate them...]

*I won't show you the code, but i'll explain it a bit:*

First, i have a **C# script for every interactable object**. This class derives from **Iinteractable** (an interface containing variables and an **Interact** function). One of these variables is a **List** of **PossibleInteractions** (which is an **enum** with **all the interactions** possible for this object).

On my **player** i have a C# script, containing a **List of all my buttons**. And in the **Update**:

I check if the **player** is **in range** and if he is **looking to my object**. If it's the case, i check the **List** of **PossibleInteractions**.
If the *"Open"* Interaction is in this list, i **activate my button** (which is on my List). Everything is automatically resized (thanks to the content fitter and the layout group).

Since i can't validate my answer until tomorrow i'll continue posting advancement...

Here is the (still early) result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Voo56.jpg

2nd part: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHNFw.jpg

I hope it will help someone :).

Comment: Since you've answered you own question, I believe you can still set it as the "accepted answer" so this doesn't show up as unanswered for other folks.

Comment: I have to wait for tommorow :(